# Java: inner test class compilation error - printing all cases of switch block

Tags: java, syntax-error

EDIT: This had been a syntax issue - had been a complete noob at the time of posting this, and had not been using a proper IDE, so my apologies to the community. Also, please try to avoid assuming that everybody on this site is a guy.

I'm currently wrestling with my inner class `DateTest`. This error message appears after compiling, and I haven't been able to figure out how to fix the bug. I've gone through many lines of code to work out the test class in trying an effort to print out all twelve cases of the switch block in the Date class.

Below I've included the errors and my code. Also might be worth mentioning that I'm writing this in an online IDE, browxy, and double checking in CodeChef.

This is my code:

```
public class Date {  

    public static int daysInMonth(int month) {  

    /** method uses a switch block and takes in a month number (1 for January, 2 for February, etc.) and returns the number of days in a month. **/  

        switch (month) {  
            case 1:  
            case 3:  
            case 5:  
            case 7:  
            case 8:  
            case 10:  
            case 12:  
                return 31;   
                break;  
            case 2:  
                return 28;  
                break;  
            case 4:  
            case 6:  
            case 9:  
            case 11:  
                return 30;  
                break;  
            default:   
                System.out.println("Invalid month.");  
                break;  
        }  
        return month;  
    }  

    public class DateTest {  

        /*test class that prints out 12 lines like: "January is 31 days long.", "February...", etc.*/   

        int month; /* <-- compilation error had been here due to missing curly brace (error = "class expected") */  
    }  

    public static void main (String [] args) {  
        month = Date.daysInMonth(1);  
        System.out.println("January is " +month+  " days long.");  
        month = Date.daysInMonth(2);  
        System.out.println("February is " +month+ " days long.");  
        month = Date.daysInMonth(3);  
        System.out.println("March is " +month+ " days long.");  
        month = Date.daysInMonth(4);  
        System.out.println("April is " +month+ " days long.");  
        month = Date.daysInMonth(5);  
        System.out.println("May is " +month+ " days long.");  
        month = Date.daysInMonth(6);  
        System.out.println("June is " +month+ " days long.");  
        month = Date.daysInMonth(7);  
        System.out.println("July is " +month+ " days long.");  
        month = Date.daysInMonth(8);  
        System.out.println("August is " +month+ " days long.");  
        month = Date.daysInMonth(9);  
        System.out.println("September is " +month+ " days long.");  
        month = Date.daysInMonth(10);  
        System.out.println("October is " +month+ " days long.");  
        month = Date.daysInMonth(11);  
        System.out.println("November is " +month+ " days long.");  
        month = Date.daysInMonth(12);  
        System.out.println("December is " +month+ " days long.");   
    }  
}
```

(EDIT: This was the first question I had asked here, and had just begun learning Java & how to program completely on my own - my advice to anyone starting out: use a decent enough computer that can support a basic IDE with syntax highlighting AND NOT an online environment/one without this, since Java/C++ punctuation may give you nightmares when you're not familiar with it.)

Comment: What do you intend `int.DateTest` to mean?

Comment: in this context DateTest  isn't an inner class

Comment: I started writing an answer and then realized that the parentheses count is wrong, so wrong that I won't attempt an answer.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly, it is hard to read.

Comment: Originally, the line read
int month = Date.daysInMonth(int);

Comment: @Svododa250 Same issue. What do you intend `Date.daysInMonth(int)` to accomplish? It doesn't mean anything in Java. You should probably just leave it out and write `int month;`.

Answer (score 1):

`month` should just be a local member in the `main` function. Just add a type declaration the first time you use it, and you should be fine:

```
public class DateTest {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int month = Date.daysInMonth(1);
        // rest of code comes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to add DateTest seems to be inner class so this class should be pulled out of the Date class inorder to compile.

Comment: thats not the error he gets....he tries to declare a static mehtod inside an inner class

Answer (score 0):

An inner class is not allowed to have a static method. Only static classes and Toplevel classes are allowed to

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Date
{
    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year)
    {
        if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)
        {

            return true;
        }
        else
        {

            return false;
        }
    }

    public static int daysInMonth(int month, boolean isLeapYear)
    {

        /**
         * method uses a switch block and takes in a month number (1 for
         * January, 2 for February, etc.) and returns the number of days in a
         * month.
         **/

        switch (month)
        {
        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 10:
        case 12:
            return 31;
        case 2:
            if (isLeapYear)
            {
                return 29;
            }
            else
            {
                return 28;
            }
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            return 30;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid month.");
            break;
        }
        return month;
    }

    /*
     * test class that prints out 12 lines like: "January is 31 days long.",
     * "February...", etc.
     */

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int year = in.nextInt();
        boolean isLeapYear = isLeapYear(year);
        int month = 0;
        month = Date.daysInMonth(1, isLeapYear);
        System.out.println("January is " + month + " days long.");
        month = Date.daysInMonth(2, isLeapYear);
        System.out.println("February is " + month + " days long.");
        month = Date.daysInMonth(3, isLeapYear);
        System.out.println("March is " + month + " days long.");
        month = Date.daysInMonth(4, isLeapYear);
        System.out.println("April is " + month + " days long.");
        month = Date.daysInMonth(5, isLeapYear);
        System.out.println("May is " + month + " days long.");
        month = Date.daysInMonth(6, isLeapYear);
        System.out.println("June is " + month + " days long.");
        month = Date.daysInMonth(7, isLeapYear);
        System.out.println("July is " + month + " days long.");
        month = Date.daysInMonth(8, isLeapYear);
        System.out.println("August is " + month + " days long.");
        month = Date.daysInMonth(9, isLeapYear);
        System.out.println("September is " + month + " days long.");
        month = Date.daysInMonth(10, isLeapYear);
        System.out.println("October is " + month + " days long.");
        month = Date.daysInMonth(11, isLeapYear);
        System.out.println("November is " + month + " days long.");
        month = Date.daysInMonth(12, isLeapYear);
        System.out.println("December is " + month + " days long.");
    }

}
```